# Is there a function to raycast both UI elements and objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a function that raycasts both UI elements and objects based on the screen coordinates, but I don't really know how to do this. Ideally the function would return the first gameObject that the raycast hit.

```
    GameObject OnClick(Vector2 pos)
    {
        // Returns a UI element or a Object based on screen coordinates
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html). We can read here that Raycast is interacting with everything that has some kind of collider. So to find UI elements the only thing you have to do is add colliders to them. You can observe that this method works by adding to the Text a collider and creating something above it in the scene with this script:

```
if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit");
    }
```

In console you should observe "Hit" messages.

If you want to detect only UI elements you can add the LayerMask parameter and change your code a little.
[image]

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LayerMask UILayerMask;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, Mathf.Infinity, UILayerMask))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit");
        }
    }
}
```